# How to find directory of some command?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I know that when you are on shell, the only commands that can be used are the ones that can be found on some directory set on PATH.
Even I don't know how to see what dirs are on my PATH variable (and this is another good question that could be answered), what I'd like to know is:

I come to shell and write:

```
$ lshw
```

I want to know a command on shell that can tell me WHERE this command is located. In other words, where this "executable file" is located?

Something like:

```
$ location lshw
/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 266, accepted):

If you're using Bash or zsh, use this:

```
type -a lshw
```

This will show whether the target is a builtin, a function, an alias or an external executable. If the latter, it will show each place it appears in your `PATH`.

```
bash$ type -a lshw
lshw is /usr/bin/lshw
bash$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
bash$ zsh
zsh% type -a which
which is a shell builtin
which is /usr/bin/which
```

In Bash, for functions `type -a` will also display the function definition. You can use `declare -f functionname` to do the same thing (you have to use that for zsh, since `type -a` doesn't).

Comment: Thank everybody who answered, but this answer was the most exciting! Thank you! I was thinking that I'm crazy, because I defined (a long time ago) a way to do this: 'update', and this has been doing 'apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade' for me. But for now, I was trying to find some update.sh file somewhere, and I couldn't find it. That's why I started this question. But now, using 'type -a update' I found that this was just an alias defined on my .bashrc located on my ~home. Really thank you.

Comment: @Gabriel: If you're not familiar with `locate` it can help find files. It uses a database that's maintained by `updatedb` which is run from a cron job. Since `locate` searches a database rather than the whole filesystem it's much faster than `find` (which could be used as a last resort).

Comment: Thank you. I'll study this tool, and see how updatedb is scheduled to run on Ubuntu's cronjob.

Comment: Sometimes `type -a` can be confusing. e.g. in case of `nvm` which is a bash function I needed to do: `type -a nvm | head -n1` to find out what exactly is `nvm`.

Comment: @MarinosAn: For functions, `type -a` outputs the function definition as well as the type of executable. The risk with using `head` is that in the case of names with more than one type, the additional types wouldn't be output. You might want to look at `type -t`.

Comment: Not a script-friendly command. It can return one or more lines, depending on whether there is an alias with that name, so you can't just do `ABS_PATH_TO_CMD=$(type -a cmd)`, you have to parse the output. But a `whereis -b cmd | awk '{print $2}'` seems to work fine for script purposes.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Try `type -p`.

Answer (score 93):

Like this:

```
which lshw
```

To see all of the commands that match in your path:

```
which -a lshw
```

Comment: also which -a lshw to see all of the commands that match in your path.

Comment: I believe this only works with commands (executables on the $PATH), not functions.

Comment: `which` is problematic because there are multiple implementations, many of which do entirely the wrong thing, and others of which seem to work fine, but have odd surprises. You should prefer `type` instead.

Comment: Doesn't work for aliases and bash functions. At least on ubuntu. Better use `type -a lshw`

Answer (score 23):

`PATH` is an environment variable, and can be displayed with the echo command:

```
echo $PATH
```

It's a list of paths separated by the colon character '`:`'

The `which` command tells you which file gets executed when you run a command:

```
which lshw
```

sometimes what you get is a path to a symlink; if you want to trace that link to where the actual executable lives, you can use `readlink` and feed it the output of `which`:

```
readlink -f $(which lshw)
```

The `-f` parameter instructs `readlink` to keep following the symlink recursively.

Here's an example from my machine:

```
$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox

$ readlink -f $(which firefox)
/usr/lib/firefox-3.6.3/firefox.sh
```

Comment: For me `which ack` returns `ack: aliased to …`, so won't work in a script.

Answer (score 5):

```
~$ echo $PATH
/home/jack/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
~$ whereis lshw
lshw: /usr/bin/lshw /usr/share/man/man1/lshw.1.gz
```

Comment: Some elaboration might be helpful to future readers: to find the binary you gotta use `-b` option, and then you can combine it with `awk` to get the path. So, something like: `whereis -b ack | awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 5):

### TLDR Answer

Use: **`whereis -b lshw`**.

### Explanation

Use the `whereis` command.  From the [man page:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html)

> `whereis` - locate the binary, source, and manual page files for a command

### Commonly-Used Switches

In addition, you can specify what you're looking for:

- `whereis -b packagename` : Source for location of binaries.
- `whereis -m packagename` : Source for location of manuals.
- `whereis -s packagename` : Source for location of source code.

In your case, since you're looking for the binary, you'll want:  **`whereis -b lshw`**.

There are other switches with this command, check them out at the [man page.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html)  If there is no file associated with a packagename, you'll see a blank line.

### Examples

Here's some real world use:

```
holdoffhunger@tower:~$ whereis grep
grep: /bin/grep /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1posix.gz

holdoffhunger@tower:~$ whereis -m grep
grep: /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1posix.gz

holdoffhunger@tower:~$ whereis -s grep
grep:
```

Comment: `whereis` is not a standard command. Better to use the POSIX-specified `type` and `command`.

Answer (score 3):

In the TENEX C Shell, **tcsh**, one can list a command's location(s), or if it is a built-in command, using the `where` command e.g.:

```
tcsh% where python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

tcsh% where cd
cd is a shell built-in
/usr/bin/cd
```

Comment: There was a time when `tcsh` was popular but that was before open source Bourne-compatible shells became widely available.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `type -a` is `command -V`

Since most of the times I am interested in the first result only, I also pipe from head. This way the screen will not flood with code in case of a bash function.

```
command -V lshw | head -n1
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more about `command -V`? I see usage of `command -v` and I don't know the difference(s) between the two.

Comment: `-V` is a bit more verbose. It will print `lshw is /usr/bin/lshw` while `-v` will just print `/usr/bin/lshw`

Comment: Where could I find the documentation of `command` itself?

Comment: @VimNing Did you try `command --help`?

Comment: Yes, but I got `zsh: command not found: --help`, just tried it again the same result.

Comment: @VimNing Then you can do: `man zshbuiltins`. Then scroll a bit and you will find the documentation of `command` builtin.

Answer (score 1):

The Korn shell, `ksh`, offers the `whence` built-in, which identifies other shell built-ins, macros, etc.  The `which` command is more portable, however.

Comment: In ksh, `whence -a` is similar to Bash's `type -a`.

Answer (score 1):

In **zsh** (in my case the current version is 5.9), you can check the directory of some command using `=` as prefix.
For example, if you want to know where is located the `mkdir` command you can use:

```
$> ls -l =mkdir
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 76216 Jun 14 20:49 /usr/bin/mkdir
```

Or more simplificated:

```
$> echo =mkdir
/usr/bin/mkdir
```

**Note:** This method only works for commands that are available in your current shell according to your `$PATH` environment variable. So, if your `$PATH` has the value **"/home/user/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"** only the commands under those 3 paths will be available.