# Recursive xattr fails horribly

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, xattr

I've been trying to figure out a way to recursively remove all of the `xattr` for some files, however, none of the [previous methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x) seem to work anymore; there might be a newly introduced bug too?

```
$ xattr -rc .
option -r not recognized

$ xattr -c .
option -c not recognized
```

*..and now the grand finale!*

```
$ find . -exec xattr -l {} \;
com.apple.FinderInfo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/xattr", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xattr/tool.py", line 200, in main
    print(_dump(attr_value))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xattr/tool.py", line 77, in _dump
    printable = s.translate(_FILTER)
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

Oh look it found an `xattr` amongst the muck... it would be interesting to know how, what or who destroyed the `xattr` tool so badly. I just need to recursively remove extended attributes, really!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to have a nonstandard `xattr` command installed in /usr/local/bin/xattr (the standard one that ships with macOS is /usr/bin/xattr). Those are Python errors, so maybe it's [this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr/)? Anyway, it doesn't use the same syntax as the standard one, so having it installed is going to cause confusion; I'd recommend either removing it or renaming it to something distinct; otherwise it's likely to break any scripts (yours or system) that try to use `xattr`.

Comment: removing `/usr/local/bin/xattr` and leaving the default `/usr/bin/xattr` solved my problem

Comment: For those having the same problem as me, apparently Anaconda has its own `xattr` in its default "base" environment. To work around this, just `conda deactivate` and go on with your day.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well.  and I believe is due to my `$PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

My `user local bin` comes before my `system usr/bin`.

Thanks to these posts I figured out the problem.

xattr was installed in two locations.

> Show whether the target is a builtin, a function, an alias or an external executable.[(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870462/1896134) /

```
type -a xattr
# xattr is /usr/local/bin/xattr
# xattr is /usr/bin/xattr
```

and they are different for sure.

```
/usr/local/bin/xattr -h
usage: xattr [-slz] file [file ...]
       xattr -p [-slz] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -w [-sz] attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
       xattr -d [-s] attr_name file [file ...]

The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.

options:
  -h: print this help
  -s: act on symbolic links themselves rather than their targets
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value)
  -z: compress or decompress (if compressed) attribute value in zip format
```

VS.

```
/usr/bin/xattr -h
usage: xattr [-l] [-r] [-s] [-v] [-x] file [file ...]
       xattr -p [-l] [-r] [-s] [-v] [-x] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -w [-r] [-s] [-x] attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
       xattr -d [-r] [-s] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -c [-r] [-s] file [file ...]

The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to the string attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.
The fifth form (-c) deletes (clears) all xattrs.

options:
  -h: print this help
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value and hex output has offsets and
      ascii representation)
  -r: act recursively
  -s: act on the symbolic link itself rather than what the link points to
  -v: also print filename (automatic with -r and with multiple files)
  -x: attr_value is represented as a hex string for input and output
```

So, if you do want to keep both for whatever reason, then you can just call them explicitly like so:

```
/usr/bin/xattr -lr ~

/usr/local/bin/xattr -l ~
```