# Forgot where I installed pip. Need directory

Tags: python, pip

I installed pip for python 3 on my laptop a year ago and now I forgot where I installed it . But I need to know the location now normal searching for pip folder is not working can somebody help!

I already tried to install pycharm so that I could find where it is, but it was not very much helpful.

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac OS, linux? following this post suggestion [Retrieving python module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/retrieving-python-module-path) you could inspect the output of `import pip;
print pip.__file__`

Comment: Sorry to mention I am on Windows

Comment: that's fine. if you run those two lines into a python interpreter, it should work in Windows, too. open the Command Prompt, type python, enter those two lines and see what it returns.

Comment: @davedwards found pip init file and pip folder but pip install command is not working yet

Comment: what do you mean it is not working? in Windows command prompt, does just `pip` do anything? or do you get `'pip' is not recognized as an internal command`, etc..?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash, the default shell on OS X and some linux distros, use this:

```
type -a pip
```

[Shell - How to find directory of some command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869100/shell-how-to-find-directory-of-some-command)